# Is there a way to stop the AWS Elasticsearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I setup an AWS Elasticsearch Domain recently but I didn't see a way to stop it (like you can with an EC2 instance), which means I'm continuously billed. At this stage I just need to do some testing and don't require a full-time cluster.

The only option I see is to delete the domain, am I missing something?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-gsg-deleting.html states "delete the domain when you are finished experimenting with it or you might incur charges", which would seem to indicate deletion is required. I'm not aware of a way to stop AWS ElasticSearch temporarily.

Comment: ES in AWS is probably shared instance. Thus, you can't just stop own one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will have to delete the cluster for billing to stop. However, if you want to backup the data for later experiments, you can take [manual snapshots](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains.html#es-managedomains-snapshots) (link rotten, check [archived page here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170810131300/https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains.html#es-managedomains-snapshots)) of the indices to your S3 buckets.

The next time you spawn a cluster, just restore the snapshot :)

Comment: I also realized that - I deleted the ES domain manually in my test environment to save money. But I had a hard time deploying anything afterwards, as CloudFormation would not recreate it because of the mess I made by manually deleting it and not being able to redeploy all the lambda functions that depend on the ES domain.

Any suggestions to fix that?

Comment: @EsbenvonBuchwald haven't worked at all with cloudformation. sorry :(

Comment: @hjpotter92 - That link is dead, is it still possible to do manual snapshots of indicies and restore them?

Comment: @timhj hmm, I can't find the link for older ES service on wayback anymore, but if you've moved to opensearch (which i haven't tried); the equivalent docs are here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/managedomains-snapshots.html#managedomains-snapshot-create

Comment: @timhj nvm, updated the reply with archived link (https://web.archive.org/web/20170810131300/https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains.html#es-managedomains-snapshots)

Comment: @hjpotter92 - thanks, the AWS link is perfect.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to stop the cluster today. What I did to reduce my bill was that I edited the cluster to reduce the instance type to a t2.small instance which is significantly cheaper than the previous instance.

Then when I needed to resume testing I changed the instance type back to what I required.

Comment: this is the best solution actually. I had read somewhere that I needed a t2.medium but I'm reducing the instance to the smallest (nano) and will take it from there.